# Unable to do a backup?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008

Backup is the most fundamental of data recovery approaches and I have the latest, most advanced operating system from Microsoft (Server 2008 R2) and I can't make backup work!

the situation: I'm running the OS under VMWare, and I want to back the system up to the host's drives.  I can access the host via UNC like this:

```
\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Thorn
```

but if I try to back up to it, I can't.  it pukes with the error:

```
C:\> wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:"\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Thorn" -include:C: -vssFull -quiet
wbadmin 1.0 - Backup command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2004 Microsoft Corp.


Note: The backed up data cannot be securely protected at this destination.
Backups stored on a remote shared folder might be accessible by other
people on the network. You should only save your backups to a location
where you trust the other users who have access to the location or on a
network that has additional security precautions in place.

Retrieving volume information...
This will back up volume Local Disk(C:) to \\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Thorn.
The directory is not a subdirectory of the root directory.
```

I did find an [[old posting](https://serverfault.com/questions/35785/windows-server-backup-fails-before-starting-with-message-the-directory-is-not-a) (from 2009) regarding the same problem (with no solution).  it's really difficult to think after all these updates and service packs the backup is still broken.  anyone know wtf?

Comment: VMware is a company, not a product. I'm guessing you're using VMware Server (yuck), but please specify what product and version you're using.

Comment: I think you want the serverrant.com site, it might be better suited :-)

Comment: Windows Server's built-in backup tools often prove inadequate. You might want to try something like [BackupAssist](http://www.backupassist.com/).

Comment: @Mile Erickson, indeed. I'm guessing no one must use Windows Backup if it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Disk2vhd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415). It's a really neat utility that just works and it looks like it may fit your needs as described. It has very little "drag along" requirements - running across a network share is no problem. The side-bonus is that the output format is also pretty VM friendly as well.

Comment: The VHD backup output is mountable and ready to boot (if you wish and if all the drivers are "happy" with the VM environment).